# How to ensure that file contents from a url write successfully to a file

Tags: java

I am using code to write contents to a file from a url. Here is the code

```
public void copyFileFromUrl(URL source, File target) throws IOException {
    try {

        if (!target.exists()) {

            target.createNewFile();
            log.debug("target file created for " + target);

            log.debug("downloading source ....");
            InputStream in = source.openStream();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

        } else {
            log.debug("skipping creation of asset");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("trouble with " + target);
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Now what is happening , suppose file size is 40kb, now during writing if i have connection reset or any kind of exception, then all the contents are not written completely or sometimes nothing is written and i have a file taht has 0 size or less size than the original file on the url.

I want to ask is there any way by which i assure that the whole file is written completely from the url and if any kind of exception accour during writing then i try three times to write and after third attempt i log the message that file is not written completely ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to get the content length in your case?

Comment: @devnull No i don't know the file size on the url. I just gave an example of 40 kb. Are you asking this ?

Comment: Why are you catching Exception and returning if you get an IOException?

Comment: If you can get the content length from the server, then you can determine whether the file was fetched completely or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public void copyFileFromUrl(URL source, File target, int count) throws IOException {
try {

    if (!target.exists()) {

        target.createNewFile();
        log.debug("target file created for " + target);

        log.debug("downloading source ....");
        InputStream in = source.openStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

    } else {
        log.debug("skipping creation of asset");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.debug("trouble with " + target);
    if(count < 3){
        target.delete();
        copyFileFromUrl(source, target, count++);
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: You should add `in.close()` and `out.close()` before calling `target.delete()`, otherwise the stream will open and file can not be deleted. Also it should `copyFileFromUrl(source, target, ++count);`, otherwise it will be always sending 0 to function and finally the stack will blow up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right after this block of code, you know that you've had a successful copy.

```
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
```

Set a global int to 0 outside of the method, and set it to -1 after the block above completes.  Add 1 to the global int inside of the catch block.

You execute the method until the global int is less than zero or greater than 3.  You'll also have to delete the target file each time you get an exception, so you don't fail with that condition.

Comment: Hhmm thanks.. Is there any way by which i get the file size on the url. Like after opening input stream from url, i get the file size and after writing to the file i match the size of both files and proceed accordingly. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can add up the len values.  As I said, if you get to the point in the execution after you've written all the bytes, you've written all the bytes.  Any exception brings you to the catch clause.

Comment: I was wondering that why were you said `set a global int to 0`. But please correct me if i wrong, this is because no matter from where my method is calling, i just need to modify this method, else i need to modify the each invocation to this method call from `fileWriter.copyFileFromUrl(earl, new File(absoluteFileName));` to `fileWriter.copyFileFromUrl(earl, new File(absoluteFileName), 0);` and also change the method signature from `public void copyFileFromUrl(URL source, File target) throws IOException {..}` ....cont

Comment: to `public void copyFileFromUrl(URL source, File target, int count) throws IOException {..}`. Am i right ? Also please tell me as i am using this method in a web application, so the global declaration in a class is `public static int count = 0` or `public int count = 0` ? I mean static is fine or it should be class variable ?